# Which of these dependencies includes a ZIP file that contains ELF files?

Tags: android, google-play

I've been told by Google that "Your app (com.package.name) includes a ZIP file which contains ELF files." I have searched my project. I haven't used a zip file or ELF file anywhere in my project. Thus, it must be in one of my dependencies, but I don't know which one.

I used the following dependencies:

```
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
implementation 'io.appsfly.android.utils:micro-app:1.2.22'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.+'
implementation 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

Which of these dependencies "includes a ZIP file which contains ELF files"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a customer service question.

Comment: Try unpacking your APK and look if you can find a suspicious ZIP file. Of course it is also possible to that a library downloads this ZIP at runtime. (Your APK is a ZIP, you might need to replace `.apk` with `.zip`)

Comment: A question which is "what violates Google's Play Store Policy" is off-topic, because it requires us to evaluate what Google means by their policies, which is something that only Google can accurately interpret. However, you could rephrase your question to be "Which of these dependencies includes a ZIP file which contains ELF files, or otherwise downloads executable code (e.g. dex, JAR, .so files) from a source other than Google Play?" If you phrase it like that, without asking for interpretation of Google Play Store policies, then the question could be on-topic.

Comment: You may consider that only semantics, but they matter in something like this. Currently, this question reads mostly like "why am I violating policy". Stated the other way, you take on responsibility for interpreting the policy and are just asking about factual information, not interpretation of policy.

Comment: My app got removed for the same reason. I cannot find any zip file in the decompiled APK, apart from a `publicsuffixes.gz` file which just contain a text file... (no ELF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for sure. But looking at your dependencies, when I google for AppsFly it seems like a platform which delivers dynamic code to apps. And Google Play policy says (as you quote)

> An app distributed on Google Play may not modify, replace, or update itself using any method other than Google Play's update mechanism.

So using AppsFly might be against the Policy. To clarify, I know nothing about AppsFly as their website doesn't have much information, but it sure sounds like it breaks the Google Play policy.

Comment: Let me check. Appsfly using for getting events.

Comment: The problem is with "AppsFly" dependencies only. I removed it completely and uploaded into playstore 2 weeks back. The problem resolved. Thank you very much for identify my problem.

Comment: the same problem comes again. I had posted question again. could help to resolve my issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53794203/which-dependencies-includes-a-zip-file-that-contains-elf-files