# Which dependencies includes a ZIP file that contains ELF files?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I've been told by Google that

> Hi,
>
> Thanks for contacting the Google Play team.
>
> Status: App not available on Google Play
>
> I’ve reviewed your appeal request and found that your app still
>   violates Google Play Policy. I’ve included details below about the
>   specific issue with your app and what you can do to get your app back
>   on Google Play.
>
> Step 1: Fix the policy violation with your app
>
> During review, we found that your app violates the Malicious Behavior
>   policy. We don’t allow apps that steal data, secretly monitor or harm
>   users, or are otherwise malicious. The following are explicitly
>   prohibited: viruses, trojan horses, malware, spyware or any other
>   malicious software.
>
> If your app was developed by a third party, we recommend contacting
>   them to verify that they designed your app to comply with our
>   policies.
>
> You can read through the Malicious Behavior policy page for more
>   details and examples of common violations..
>
> Your app includes a ZIP file which contains ELF files. An app may not
>   download executable code (e.g. dex, JAR, .so files) from a source
>   other than Google Play.
>
> Please update your app to fix this issue. You may also want to double
>   check that your app complies with all other Developer Program
>   Policies, as additional enforcement could occur if there are further
>   policy violations.
>
> This rejection doesn't impact the standing of your Google Play
>   Developer Account, but repeated violations can result in the
>   suspension of this app or your Google Play Developer account.

I have analyzed and reviewed code in entire app. i cant able to find that issue, where the ELF zip file downloads. Can anybody help me to solve this issue. 
I used the following dependencies,

> ```
> dependencies {
>  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include:['*.jar'])
> androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',
> {
>     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
> })
>
> implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
> //noinspection GradleCompatible
> implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
> implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
> //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
> implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.39.0'
> implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
> implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
> implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
>
> //include only the necessary dependencies to avoid the Android dex limit
> implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1'
>
> testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
> implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
>     transitive = true;
>     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
> }
>
> // Third party library
> implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
> annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
> implementation 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'
> implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
> implementation 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
> implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5' }
> ```

Manifest.xml file permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Google rejected my app. I also checked in apk analyzer images attached.  Anybody help to identify issue. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: An ELF file is basically a Linux executable. You might want to take a peek at your APK file (e.g., using Android Studio's APK Analyzer) and see if you see what Google Play sees.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did that same. There is no zip or ELF file is not found. Please check the images. i have attached

Comment: What is in `assets/`?

Comment: @CommonsWare its contains font files Images updated in the questions.